# How to detect APC UPS battery usage and run a script when on battery

Tags: automation, ups, electrical-power, apc, apc-smart-ups

I have a couple APC UPS -

- Smart-UPS RT 6000 RM XL
- Smart-UPS RT 5000 RM XL

Unfortunately the power in my office likes to go out (out of my control) and hence the equipment powered by these UPS shuts down. They power a VMware infrastructure environment (VMware Lab Manager) and what I'd like to do is detect when one is on battery (say has been for x amount of time or has x percentage left) and run a script on this event.

What software do I need to detect a on-battery event and have it run a script?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check rear the Smart-UPS? Usually these models have already pre-installed the SmartSlot™ Card (with network port).

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the APC PowerChute?

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1007036

Comment: The only comment I would add is that this may also required the purchase and installation of an APC Smart-UPS Network Card in order for the batteries to trigger remote shutdowns and even WOL.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of using PowerChute and hooking up a system via USB but I didn't know if PowerChute could be configured to run a script when the UPS goes on battery. I'll give it a try. I also came across [PowerChute Network Shutdown](http://www.apc.com/products/family/?id=127) and wasn't sure if this was more of what I wanted...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apcupsd`, it's in most repositories. It supports both USB and RS232 connections as well as networked communication (where the network server can be both the UPS itself as well as another `apcupsd` instance).

It has default scripts that should gracefully shutdown your machine. The scripts that do that are defined  in apcupsd config file, you should be able to switch them to something different.